# Get sum and percentage of a given dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['adam', 'adam', 'adam'], 
                   'meal': ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner'], 
                   'cost': [75, 120, 250]})

   name       meal  cost
0  adam  breakfast    75
1  adam      lunch   120
2  adam     dinner   250
```

How can I get sum of all meals and insert to the last row and add a percentage column, as follows

```
   name       meal  cost  percent  
0  adam  breakfast    75    16.85
1  adam      lunch   120    26.97
2  adam     dinner   250    56.18
3  adam      total   445
```

I tried to use `cumsum()` but it ended like this

```
df['total'] = df.groupby('name').cumsum()

   name       meal  cost  total
0  adam  breakfast    75     75
1  adam      lunch   120    195
2  adam     dinner   250    445
```

Comment: please include your attempt, this task is so easy we need to know where the problem is

Comment: Agree that the question is simple enough to have the question author answer "what have you tried?". But left an answer just in case anyone else is stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute `percentage` then add one row with value at the end of dataframe.

```
sum_cost = df['cost'].sum()
df['percent'] = df['cost'] / sum_cost * 100
df.loc[len(df)] = ['adam', 'total'] + [sum_cost, df['percent'].sum()] 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   name       meal  cost     percent
0  adam  breakfast    75   16.853933
1  adam      lunch   120   26.966292
2  adam     dinner   250   56.179775
3  adam      total   445  100.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

## Access the `cost` column and to get its sum

```
>>> df['cost'].sum()
445
```

## Then divide the column values by the sum and multiply it by 100

```
>>> df['cost'] / df['cost'].sum() * 100

0    16.853933
1    26.966292
2    56.179775
Name: cost, dtype: float64
```

## Assign the output to a column named `percent`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['adam', 'adam', 'adam'], 
                   'meal': ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner'], 
                   'cost': [75, 120, 250]})

df['percent'] = df['cost'] / df['cost'].sum() * 100
```